# SSL error accessing QGIS

Tags: qgis, ssl, ssl-error

I am trying to QGIS 3.16.2 and I am getting an error message saying:

> SSL errors occurred accessing URL

The certificate has expired.

How can I rectify this?

Here's an image for more detail:

[image]